# Delete rows in a spreadsheet where <condition> when column of <condition> is unknown

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I need to find the word "Overdue" and "Due" in a spreadsheet, but the column they appear in will be variable, as will the number of records (rows). I need to delete all rows that do NOT have these values in the data, then total up the data left on the sheet after the others have been deleted. Any clues?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of how your excel sheet looks like alongwith which values in data you want to total up? It is difficult to understand the question by mere textual description.

Comment: not sure how i do that let me try and explain better....The spreadhet in col A has cleint names and other project details inclusing costs in ciolumns to BJ (but this may change if other columns get added.  the rows list individula projects of which there are many.  each month we have to work out the due and overdue income - have a excel function in column BL (but this could change each mth) that flags which projects are due overdue and OK.  I want to scroll through each row and delete any columns and delet the ok ones (from a copy sheet) and then total up the column so we know how much owed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

Put this into a macro to run

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim usedRange As Range

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    Set usedRange = sheet.usedRange

Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim columnCount As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer

    rowCount = usedRange.Rows.Count
    columnCount = usedRange.Columns.Count

    For iRow = rowCount To 1 Step -1
        For iColumn = 1 To columnCount
            If ((InStr(1, LCase(usedRange(iRow, iColumn)), "overdue") > 0) Or (InStr(1, LCase(usedRange(iRow, iColumn)), "due") > 0)) Then
                usedRange.Range(Cells(iRow, 1), Cells(iRow, columnCount)).Delete
            End If
        Next iColumn
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it looks great but i tried running this code on my sheet and got a mismatch error on this line

If ((InStr(1, LCase(usedRange(iRow, iColumn)), "overdue") > 0) Or (InStr(1, LCase(usedRange(iRow, iColumn)), "due") > 0)) Then


the column I'm looking st will have just text in it...will this make a difference to this line?

Comment: which version of excel are you running?

Comment: OK, i did this in 2007. Things to check for with type mismatch might be LCase(usedRange(iRow, iColumn)). Check that usedRange(iRow, iColumn) is in fact returning a string. Check this by adding a watch to see the value returned.

Comment: many thanks for your time and effort - i'll see what i can do from here....

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something with ADO.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strWhere As String
Dim i As Integer

''http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] AS s "

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

For i = 0 To rs.fields.Count - 1
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND (UCase(s.[" _
        & rs.fields(i).Name & "] ) Not Like '%DUE%' Or s.[" _
        & rs.fields(i).Name & "] Is Null) "
Next

strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & Mid(strWhere, 5)
rs.Close

rs.Open strSQL

For i = 0 To rs.fields.Count - 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.fields(i).Name
Next

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel should be able to coerce any value into a string except an error.  So if you have formulas that return errors, that may be causing the type mismatch.  Here's another way using the Find method that would avoid that problem.  Find can be slower that looping through the columns, but if you don't have a ton of data, you won't notice it.

```
Sub DeleteOverDue()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rFound As Range

    'Loop backward through the used range
    For i = Sheet1.usedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        'Should find "due" and "overdue" because of xlPart
        Set rFound = Sheet1.usedRange.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Find("due", , xlValues, xlPart)
        'If it's not found, delete the row
        If rFound Is Nothing Then
            Sheet1.usedRange.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Note: This code deletes data so please use it on a copy of your real data until you know that it works for you.